# Convergence of a r.v. in probability to a constant in probability

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_n$ and $X_n'$ be independent and with the same distribution function $F_n$, and suppose that $X_n - X_n' \rightarrow 0$ in distribution. Show that there exist constants $a_n$ such that $X_n - a_n \rightarrow 0$ in probability.

The hint says to use $a_n = \inf \{x : F_n(x) \geq 1/2\}$. My intuition is that the hypothesis $X_n - X_n' \rightarrow 0$ suggests that $X_n$ and $X_n'$ are both "very close to being constant", which implies that $X_n - a_n \rightarrow 0$ in distribution. Also, there is a theorem stating that $X \rightarrow a$ in probability is equivalent to $X \rightarrow a$ in distribution if $a$ is constant, right?

Comment: I have no answer yet (and time lacks), but a suggestion that might help: have a look at $Y_n:=X_n-a_n$ and $Y'_n:=X'_n-a_n$. Then it must be shown that $Y_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability. It might make things a bit less complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symmetrization inequalities (see for instance page 149 of Feller's *Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications*, Vol. 2) yield for all $\epsilon > 0$,
$$
\Pr(|X_n - a_n| > \epsilon) \leq 2 \Pr(|X_n-X_n'| > \epsilon),
$$
from which the result is obvious since you already observed that $X_n - X_n' \to 0$ in probability.